# Hibernate: HQL index column names

Tags: hibernate, inner-join, hql

I was able to get the results of my query. Sample query:

```
String hql = "Select tbl1.name tbl1_name, tbl2.name tbl2_name 
FROM table_1 tbl1
INNER JOIN table_2 tbl2 ON tbl1.id = tbl2.tbl1_id";

Query query  = entityManager.createQuery(hql);
List <String> result = query.getResultList();
```

When I do getResultList() the result is a list of object string with a number index.

```
 [
     0: {
          0: "Tbl 1 name 1"
          1: "Tbl 2 name 1"
     }
     1: {
          0: "Tbl 1 name 2"
          1: "Tbl 2 name 2"
     }
     .....
 ]
```

and I would like the result be:

```
 [
     0: {
          tbl1_name: "Tbl 1 name 1"
          tbl2_name: "Tbl 2 name 1"
     }
     1: {
          tbl1_name: "Tbl 1 name 2"
          tbl2_name: "Tbl 2 name 2"
     }
     .....
 ]
```

is this possible?

Comment: How did you arrive at the first JSON output?

Comment: Hey, updated my question for more details. Please see question. Hope that's what your looking for

Comment: anyone?? I did this by manually creating a name of there index by looping in the result with another List object. But, is there a way for Hibernate to handle this automatically?